# Mysql select from a array

Tags: mysql, select

To select something from the data base we could use:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName where name="Ed"
```

But what if I need to select something from a given array, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM ("Bob","Sam","Ed") where name="Ed"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: you can fake up a fable, `select * from (select 'bob' union select 'sam' union ....) as foo `

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/64737

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
(SELECT "Bob" name UNION SELECT "Sam" UNION SELECT "Ed") t
WHERE t.name="Ed"
```

But it has almost no sense. Because if you set all data as constant static values you can just:

```
SELECT "Ed"
```

there is no reason even to call mysql :-)

Comment: In OP's case, no it doesn't make much sense. However it would if some MySQL functions needs to be called. I'd really appreciate if I can do this: `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FooTable.Time) FROM (SELECT ('1428384605','1429657398','1429686889') as Time) AS FooTable`

Comment: @LionetChen but do you have `WHERE time='1429686889'` at the end? ;-)

Comment: I don't have that filter :P hence I said "in OP's case". I know I could've achieved the conversion with Excel but I was in the SQL query editor and just too lazy to open up Excel to type in those formulas LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
    SELECT * FROM ( 
        select "Bob" as name
        from dual
        union
        select "Sam" as name
        from dual
        union 
        select "Ed"as name
        from dual ) as t
    where t.name="Ed";
```